# How do I get xbox one party and Skype voice through my headset?

Tags: xbox-one

When I join a party or go on Skype, the audio of the people talking to me comes out of my tv, but the microphone on my headset is being used. How can I set it so their voices come through the headset?

Comment: What is your Kinect setting when chatting?